# Microservice async architecture to implement services working interrelated

Tags: asynchronous, microservices, backend

I have a question microservice architecture about services working interrelated wih each other.
For example;
Let's think the below senario in e-commerce.

We have BuyProduct Endpoint and request to this endpoint.

1. Browser request
2. BuyProduct executes.
   BuyProduct has three service calls
     1)Payment Service Call
       if payment service fail
             return false;
       else
            continue;
       2)Stock Service Call
       if stock service fail
          return false;
       else
          continue;
       3)Account Service Call
       if account service fail
          return false;
       else
          continue;
3. Return to the browser success or fail

In this example,I assumed success or fail state when passing from a service call to another service.
But for example there might be a situation in which values returned from payment service call to stock service call request.

My question is ;

If we have message broker and want to make async architecture with a message broker(like rabbitmq or another).How can we implement this senario ? Will this solution be valid or Is there any solution?
What is the best practice ?
I googled but could not find a solution that satisfied me?

I am not sure that my solution I think is true.(I mean rest sync architecture)

If browser waits for immediate result and we want to gurantee our processes finish successfully or fail ,What will happen ?

When we think this senario as all-or-none,What can we do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a message broker to make this async, you will have to deal with the concept of [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). This means that for a brief period (hopefully) of time, you would have processed the payment, but have not updated the stock and the account statuses.

Your code must then be able to handle the inconsistencies. For example, there is only one item left and 2 customer both bought the item at the same time. The calls to Payment Service would work for both but one of the calls to the Stock Service would fail.

A microservice pattern that helps to manage such data consistency problems is called [Saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html). A saga is basically a mechanism to coordinate multiple microservices to work together in a manner that ensures data remain consistent. Since you mentioned that you are exploring the use of a message broker, you may want to look at the choreography based approach.

Comment: 1)What will we do if we call payment service and get paymentId and send this paymentid to stock service ?

Comment: 2)And What will we do if we have to return payment and stock completed successfully? Rest api or websocket.It sounds rest api is not a solution? Right?